# How to restore websphere configuration to lower version

Tags: websphere

Can i restore websphere configuration to lower version on same OS using ./restoreConfig command from WAS 9 to 8.5.5?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, the version, release, or maintenance level of the server is not a function of its configuration.